# is there any way or any library in node js to save polylines google map as a png image without rendering any HTML?

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, express

i am trying to save polylines google map as a png image from backend in node js without rendering any view engine.

```
i have tried a node js package "webshot" but it does not save poly lines google map.  

app.get('/testing', (req, res, next) => {

  webshot('http://localhost:3000/map/img', 'google.png', function(err) {
    // screenshot now saved to google.png
  });

})
```

i expect the output an image of poly lines google map by using node js.

Answer (score 0):

No, you need to render the HTML to create an image. End of story.

That said you can use a headless browser like https://phantomjs.org/ to do it seamlessly in the background.

```
var page = require('webpage').create();
page.open('http://localhost:3000/map/img', function() {
    setTimeout(function() {
        page.render('google.png');
        phantom.exit();
    }, 200);
});
```